# React Native: How to add script tag in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to add  tag inside the component for the React Native app. Below is my code and it doesn't seem to work.
Could anyone please tell me how to solve this issue?

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Image, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class Chatbot extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Testing</Text>
        
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.__be = window.__be || {};
      window.__be.id = "5b3a47b4b30a36000769d821";
      (function() {
          var be = document.createElement('script'); be.type = 'text/javascript'; be.async = true;
          be.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.botengine.ai/widget/plugin.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(be, s);
      })();
  </script>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: <script> tags don't work in React Native. Even if this is on a web browser, be careful that the script will be executed on every re-render. I use this library to include <script> in my ReactJS web apps. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-load-script

Comment: nmjs.com/package/react-load-script is now abandoned and unmaintained.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer for this for a while. I heard that 3rd party script tags can be injected using Webview in React native and load the script tag functionality. Can somebody post a sample answer on that if you have? I'm looking to include **_timeonsite.js_** script tag and test it out?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the code you are writing will not run in a browser.
The script tag serves to tell the BROWSER: "Hey browser, stop. We got some javascript here. Execute it", so you should forget about the script tag.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute code depending on browser environment on react-native. try to run it inside a WebView component. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

Comment: thanks Filipe, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that logic in `componentDidMount` instead.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Image, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class Chatbot extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.__be = window.__be || {};
    window.__be.id = "5b3a47b4b30a36000769d821";
    (function() {
      var be = document.createElement('script'); be.type = 'text/javascript'; be.async = true;
      be.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.botengine.ai/widget/plugin.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(be, s);
    })();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Testing</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this wouldn't work... The script that I have is the chatbot that I want to display on the app. Your answer does not do that. Do you know how to achieve this?