# How to bind remote javascript file in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, cdn

I'm trying to integrate an js library (only delivered by cdn) to my react native app. Where or how to integrate the lib?

React native apps doesn't use html file where put script tag.

Comment: Download it from the CDN and include the `.js` file directly in the app.

Comment: Hi @ceejayoz, I can't download the .js because it's a privative lib only delivered by remote. The lib is offered "compiled".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native: How to add script tag in the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139829/react-native-how-to-add-script-tag-in-the-component)

Comment: Hi @ravibagul91, thanks for your answer but it works in React, it does not in React Native. In RN raises "Can't find variable document". document is not available in RC.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible. React Native does not allow that.